# How to re-initialize a Windows phone app page after suspend and resume (Prism.StoreApps)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, prism

I have an (Prism.StoreApps) app with a page that must release a used object when the page is navigated away (in `OnNavigatedFrom`). This also happens when the app is suspended (since `OnNavigatedFrom` is invoked then). The object must be re-initialized when the app is resumed. As far as I know there is no page event that is raised when the app was resumed and the page gets into the foreground. I know about the `Suspending` event of the app. Problem is that this can't be used because re-initializing the object on the page involves an UI element on that page.

Question is how a page could be notified that it must re-initialize because of a resume.

To clarify: The object on the page is a `MediaCapture`. It must be set as the source of a `CaptureElement`. `StartPreviewAsync` must be invoked to display the media stream as a preview. This is the part of the initializing. When navigating away at least `StopPreviewAsync` must be invoked to allow other apps to use the camera. After resuming the app on the page that holds the `MediaCapture` and `CaptureElement` at least `StartPreviewAsync` must be invoked again. This cannot be done in the `Resuming` event of the app since the page for unknown reasons (assuming the `MediaCapture` and `CaptureElement` are referenced as properties of the App instance). The app just crashes when resuming (with no error information whatsoever).

Comment: I believe the OnNavigatedTo Event will be fired each time the page is reloaded - including when the app is resumed?

Comment: Would indeed be the solution, but: At least from Windows Phone 8.1 on OnNavigatedTo is not fired when the app is resumed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx ("For Windows Phone Store apps, OnNavigatedFrom() is called when the app is suspended. OnNavigatedTo() is not called when the app is resumed."). OnNavigatedTo is probably fired on resuming with Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone Silverlight. Unfortunately we choose Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone RT 8.1 and Windows 8.1 behave the same when it comes to suspend/resume in the application lifecycle. There's an excellent link on MSDN about handling the [application lifecycle with Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130647.aspx#Resuming). In short there are 2 important cases for you to handle:

- The application gets terminated after it was suspended. When re-opening the app, you'll get an OnLaunched event and Prism will handle restoring the state, creating the frame and launch a Navigate. This scenario should be handled correctly by default.
- To cover suspend/resume without termination you'll have to register an event handler for the Resuming event. Personally I would then send a message through the EventAggregator to notify your view/view model. If necessary, add a small delay on the receiving side of the message.

Comment: The EventAggregator did the trick. I now completely release and dispose the MediaCapture in OnNavigatedFrom and create and initialize it in OnNavigatedTo and the in the subscribed "AppResumed" event that I publish in the Resuming event of the app. Seems to work (no crashes anymore when resuming).